# SVG Filters results in parts being chopped off

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I'm not sure what the best way to describe this is, but I'll upload an image and you can see for yourself on [codepen](https://codepen.io/manutastic/pen/wrRddP?editors=0100).
[image]

The CSS:

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50%;
  -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
  filter: url("#goo");
}
```

The SVG Filter:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="12" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 30 -9" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Basically, I'm trying to use SVG filters to create a "gooey" effect on some circles. It pretty much works as intended, except sometimes and in some places the effect will be "cut-off."

The places where this happens changes seemingly randomly. I have tried to reproduce this in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, and the results are very inconsistent.

Is this just a case of SVG Filters being buggy? Or am I using them wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Normally when this happens, it is because the filter region isn't big enough. However I think it is fine in this case. It looks okay in Firefox. However, there are some issues in Chrome. But I think that's just a Chrome bug.

Comment: You will likely find you have better luck if you make this an SVG-only animation, rather than trying to apply SVG filters to HTML elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG filters have a [filter effects region](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion) that does not span the whole canvas, but only a bit beyond the object bounding box they work on. The default values you don't see are 10% in each direction:

```
<filter filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"
        x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%">
```

If these are not enough, choose greater values. If you prefer not to use percentages but pixel values, set `filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` and position the effects region using the coordinate system of the filtered object.